# Realm maximumDate() method cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to pull out an object of `RealmCountyEntity` with the most recent `timestamp`. However for the parameter of `maximumdate`, I get an error that it cannot resolve the symbol. Within the `RealmCountyEntity` object there is a `timestamp` variable. I think I am confused as to exactly what this method requires. According to the documentation its the field within the object where this looks, but these don't seem to be matching up. Here is my realm call:

```
RealmCountyEntity myCounty = realm.where(RealmCountyEntity.class).maximumDate(timestamp);
```

Here is the `RealmCountyEntity` object code (I removed the irrelevant getters and setters of other fields to make it more clear. Otherwise all other code is intact):

```
package com.example.claire.pullstuff.Entity;


import java.util.Date;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class RealmCountyEntity extends RealmObject {

    private Date timestamp;

    //getters and setters
    public void setTimestamp(Date t){
        timestamp = t;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp(){
        return timestamp;
    }

}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insight in this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method takes a String as input, so you should do this:

```
RealmCountyEntity myCounty = realm.where(RealmCountyEntity.class).maximumDate("timestamp");
```

That is how most of the query langue works.
You could improve the typesafety by doing this:

```
public class RealmCountyEntity extends RealmObject {
    public static final String FIELD_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    //...
}

realm.where(RealmCountyEntity.class).maximumDate(RealmCountyEntity.FIELD_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think I see the error in my query now. I was giving the wrong information and also expecting the wrong information back. Thanks so much for the help!